# transferred images from camera to pc lacks quality

Tags: images, camera, transfer

I have a canon ixy 930 is digital camera. The pictures on the camera lcd are crystal clear and the colors are bright and full of life. But when I transfered them to my pc, the photo quality turns bad. They look dull, unclear and the colors are faded yet the pictures from the internet are very clear. I connected my camera to the television set and the images look the same just like on the camera lcd. Is there something wrong on my computer? Please do help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to help without digging deeper.

Things to check:

- It's possible (though unlikely) that there's something wrong with the camera driver/software on your computer which corrupts images when downloading them. To be sure, install the latest version of Canon's software on a different PC and try transfering the pictures there, to see if there's a difference.
- The most likely explanation is that the pictures look different on your PC because your monitor has different settings. Small imperfections/blurriness is often not noticeable on a TV or the tiny camera LCD, because they have less resolution; on a PC monitor this becomes apparent. As to colors, this is a question of calibration, so again your PC may be different. Images from the Internet may look good because they were prepared differently.

Comment: To confirm whether it's a driver issue, bypass the driver completely by transferring the pictures with a card reader instead of with the camera.